# When question,answer contents are poor, and question , answer do not meet quality standards

Tags: discussion

Many questions of mine posted to English language and usage sites and to English language learners sites are considered as low-quality posts and incomprehensible.

My question is, Are questions posted in other sites taken into account for the purpose of considering the quality of the English language in stack exchange network? My concern is that the contents of the posts, flagging, comments, and title of the posts. I have viewed the highly upvoted questions and answers.
Perhaps the content quality of the question and answer posts of mine is poor that attribute might be applicable to question, answer posts to other sites as well.

English language of the posts is not up-to-the-mark. These sentences are in addition to HELP CENTER RULES and other guidelines

Comment: 1. This isn't a question about the English language. 2. If a question is deleted for being low quality, it isn't because of bad grammar. It could be because the question is incomprehensible or no research went into it. 3. I can't speak for others but when voting on whether to close a question, I have neither the time nor the inclination to look into the poster's posts on other sites. I usually don't even look at their other posts on this site.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, Are questions posted in other sites taken into account for the purpose of considering the quality of the English language in stack exchange network?

No. Each post should be judged without looking at other posts when voting or flagging.

If a question is difficult to understand, it should be closed until it is edited so that it is easier to understand. This ensures that the answers will be relevant and helpful. A certain level of English fluency is required to participate on the English language sections of Stack Exchange.

ELL users are more understanding of the difficulty a non-native English speaker faces when writing in English. However, this site is not intended to provide tutoring. You can ask for help writing your question for ELL on ELL's meta or in [ELL's main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow). Some users may be willing to help, or help you find an answer on ELL if your question has already been asked.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes moderators and the community members change the guidelines at intervals that suit them best. There are innumerable users who post highly upvoted questions and answers. moderators' decisions are final. upvoting and downvoting are done by users keeping their interests and objectives in mind. I know I have always been nice to fellow users. I remember the code of conduct. I go through "how to ask good questions?", "What topics should I avoid asking?" and the rest is my failure to understand at a time all the intricacies of the rules that turn out to be critical. All I do is to the best of my ability even though hastily and rapidly.

Comment: The original question is "Are questions posted on other sites ..." so as it stands I fail to see how this is an answer to that. Perhaps I am missing something.